# Library management system - How to store both tamil and english books details in the same table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to store a Tamil and English books details in the library management system database table, Is this possible to do, can you provide me some idea to store both the languages.

while I am trying to store the Tamil language in the DB table, the English fonts have changed completely. I don't know how to store both fonts.

I have downloaded Tamil font Bamini, and I keep the Bamini.ttf into the fonts folder, then I call the src using CSS code.

**This is my CSS code:**

```
     @fontface{
      font-family : Bamini;
src: url(fonts/Bamini.ttf);
}

td{
   font-family: Bamini;
 }
```

This is working fine but if I am trying to add an English font(English does not work). It shows like... ????????

Comment: It would help if you added some example of the problem you have, include the table definitions and the PHP code used to store the data.

Comment: Now I have attached the sample code, kindly guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only use the custom font for the relevant rows.

Something like this:

```
<td class="lang-{{ $book->language }}">
```

and then:

```
td.lang-tamil { font-family: Bamini; }
```